# My Macro uses Personal.xlsb as current filename

Tags: excel, vba

**As a beginner**, I wrote the following macro and saved it in the PERSONAL.XLSB.

I want the Excel, in the Part 6, to export the file to the same folder with the same filename.
But the Part 6 does not run. Can anyone help me please?

```
    Sub Aufräumen()
'
' Aufräumen Makro
'

'
'   1. Detele the "Mängelbericht":
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'switching off the alert button
    Sheets("Mängelbericht").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'switching on the alert button
'
'   2. Cleaning the "Protokoll":
    Sheets("Prtokoll").Select
    Columns("M:U").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("M1").Select
'
'   3. Cleaning the "Bestandaufnahme":
    Sheets("Bestandaufnahme").Select
    Columns("AB:AK").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("AB1").Select
'
'   4. Cleaning the "Messungen":
    Sheets("Messungen").Select
    Columns("O:AD").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("O1").Select
'
'   5. Back to start point
    Sheets("Prtokoll").Select
    Range("M1").Select
    
'
'   6. Save As PDF:
    ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

Here is a screentshot of the debugger:
[image]

Comment: What does the error message say? You just showed the line that it occurs in.

Comment: try using activeworkbook instead of thisworkbook?

Comment: @John: Sorry for my incomplete question. It says: Runtime error: '-2147018887 (80071779)': The document was not saved.

Comment: @Hooded One: Thans for your help. The "Activeworkbook" solved my problem. I think your suggestion can be submitted as the answer. Only one more question: My new filename became: "sample.xlsx.pdf". How can I remove the "xlsx" from the filename?

Comment: @Hooded One: I found the solution for the "xlsx" problem: ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When saving a macro to an xlsb (which is not the workbook the macro is running in), you will need to use active workbook instead of this workbook.

Comment: This answer, Activeworkbook, solved my problem. Thanks again for your help.